# Efficiently apply function to every row of a dataframe depending on another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

## Introduction

I have two dataframes. I would like to apply a function to each row of the first one. This function depends on the row and the entire second dataframe. I would like to do this efficiently.

---

## Reprudicible Example

### Setting up the dataframes

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Let the two dataframes be:

```
df0 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a':np.random.normal(0,1,5),'b':np.random.normal(0,1,5)})
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'c':np.random.normal(0,1,10),'d':np.random.normal(0,1,10)})
```

(In the real application, they are much bigger.)

I would like to find which row from `df1` is closest to each row in `df0`, where closest is defined as having the least `squared_dist` between them:

```
def squared_dist(x,y):
    return np.sum(np.square(x-y))
```

---

### What I have tried

What I do is create to `numpy` arrays from the dataframes

```
df0np=df0.to_numpy()
df1np=df1.to_numpy()
```

Iterate through these arrays:

```
res=[]
for row in df0np:
    distances = [squared_dist(row,df1np[i,]) for i in range(len(df1np))]
    index=np.argmin(distances)
    res.append(index)
```

Add the result to `df0` as a new column:

```
df0['res']=res
```

### How fast is it?

The whole code in one piece, including timings for the method described above:

```
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df0 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a':np.random.normal(0,1,5),'b':np.random.normal(0,1,5)})
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'c':np.random.normal(0,1,10),'d':np.random.normal(0,1,10)})

df0np=df0.to_numpy()
df1np=df1.to_numpy()

start=time.time()

df0np=df0.to_numpy()
df1np=df1.to_numpy()

res=[]
for row in df0np:
    distances = [squared_dist(row,df1np[i,]) for i in range(len(df1np))]
    index=np.argmin(distances)
    res.append(index)

df0['res']=res

end=time.time()
print(end-start) # prints 0.0014030933380126953
```

---

## Question

How could I make this more efficient, ie how could I achieve lower execution times? This method works fine for this example above, but in my real world application where dataframes are much bigger, this is unusably slow.

Comment: One point of optimization. Squared distance is a bijection of the absolute distance. This means you can compute `np.abs(x-y)` instead of `np.square(x-y)` and get the same matches. This should be less computationally expensive.

Comment: @mozway They are different metrics, same match isn't guaranteed. E.g, for the point `(1, 2)`, the point `(1, 5)` is closer to it than `(3, 4)` using L1 metric; it is the other way around  for L2 metric.

Comment: Yes, I had not seen that it is bidimensional

Comment: How about `df0["res"] = cdist(df0np, df1np).argmin(axis=1)` where `cdist` is from 
`scipy.spatial.distance` module; is this fast enough?

Comment: @MustafaAydın That's an improvement indeed! Takes roughly half as much time as my solution.

Comment: @mozway, thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately they are indeed different metrics.

Comment: DId you try to use pypy?